# Fast Pattern Identification

Tags: c++, pattern-matching

I am working on a project that requires me to identify certain patterns in log files in real time. The service will be load balanced spread across multiple servers and pushed several TB of log files per minute.

The original project was much smaller, and did not have the "in real time" restriction, so I wrote it in Python and used Regex to match the patterns.

I am in the process of converting the application into C++ to increase the speed of the processing, however I am not convinced that Regex is my quickest pattern recognition option.

Can anyone who has had personal experience with fast pattern recognition (i.e. did not just google a solution) provide feedback on their experience with pattern recognition?

I have found a few different libraries which are used for pattern recognition, such as SPARE parts and Regex, but I'd prefer to get the opinion of a more seasoned developer, or someone who has dealt with large scale, real time pattern recognition in the past.

### -

Side note: I realize this is a broad question and I have not presented the research I have performed prior to asking the question, however I am asking for *personal experience*, not a solution which I can easily find on Google.

Comment: If your application calls for regular expressions (i.e. the patterns lend themselves to this representation), I wouldn't write off regex, especially if you have multiple servers available to perform processing in parallel. See e.g. this page for experience with different regex engines, they are not all "slow" http://lh3lh3.users.sourceforge.net/reb.shtml

Answer (score 0):

There are a few algorithms for doing this.  This wiki article describes some of the more popular ones.  [String_searching_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm)

The brute-force way to do it is to go character by character checking to see if the pattern matches.  If some where along the pattern it does not match, then increment to the next character in the text.  But some really smart people, check the wiki article, have figured out that you can use an algorithm that lets you skips a few characters ahead.

There is a lot of material out there describing these methods, again check the wiki article, and I will do very poorly in describing them compared to what's out there.